# Image Analysis error in Content Hub

Tags: azure, content-hub

In `Sitecore Content Hub`, we imported assets using excel with an Asset Type that triggers Image Analysis, but we got an error in the background process (processing job):

```
Target completed with failures. vision_analysis: VisionClient 
execution failed: 'System.Exception: Missing     
parameters.CommandLine.BadFormatTokenError,     
CommandLine.MissingRequiredOptionError at 
Sitecore.CH.MediaProcessing.VisionClient.Program.<>c. 
<Main>b__5_2(IEnumerable 1x) in 
/src/Sitecore.CH.MediaProcessing.VisionClient/Program.cs:line 45 at 
CommandLine.ParserResultExtensions.WithNotParsed[T](ParserResult 1 
result, Action 1 action) at 
Sitecore.CH.MediaProcessing.VisionClient.Program.Main(String[] 
args) in 
/src/Sitecore.CH.MediaProcessing.VisionClient/Program.cs:line 47 ', 
vision_ocr: VisionClient execution failed: 'System.Exception: 
Missing parameters.CommandLine.BadFormatTokenError, 
CommandLine.MissingRequiredOptionError at 
Sitecore.CH.MediaProcessing.VisionClient.Program.<>c. 
<Main>b__5_2(IEnumerable 1 x) in 
/src/Sitecore.CH.MediaProcessing.VisionClient/Program.cs:line 45 at 
CommandLine.ParserResultExtensions.WithNotParsed[T](ParserResult`1 
result, Action 1 action) at 
Sitecore.CH.MediaProcessing.VisionClient.Program.Main(String[] 
args) in 
/src/Sitecore.CH.MediaProcessing.VisionClient/Program.cs:line 47
```

Does anyone have encountered this error?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the error message in text with your question, not in the image.

Comment: Thank you @SumitBhatia, I updated the question.